# контекстное меню в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Дело обстоит так:
есть у меня TreeView

```
 <TreeView x:Name="tv_dep" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,5" Width="143" >

        <TreeView.ItemTemplate >
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                <TextBlock x:Name="tb"  Text="{Binding Name}"  ContextMenuOpening="TextBlock_ContextMenuOpening">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu >
                        <ContextMenu>Add New </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

заполнение которого происходит динамически через ItemSource

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Company.Name = "MyCompany";
        Company.dep_l.Add(new Department() { Name = "First" });
        Company.dep_l.Add(new Department() { Name = "Second" });
        Company.dep_l[1].dep_l.Add(new Department() { Name = "First in First" });
        Company.dep_l[0].per_list.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Person1", Surname = "Person1", Second_name = "Person1", Birth_date = DateTime.Now });
        tv_dep.ItemsSource = Company.dep_l;

    }
```

Заполняется из `Department Company = new Department();` из класса

```
 class Department
{
    string name;
    int id;
    public List<Department> dep_l = new List<Department>();
    public List<Person> per_list = new List<Person>();
    public List<Department> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return dep_l;
        }

    }
    public List<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            return per_list;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value;  }
    }

}
```

И все бы ничего, но когда пришло время вводить ContextMenu появилась проблема. При нажатии правой клавишей на элементе контекстное меню работает, но сам элемент не выделяется ( хотя это мне как раз таки и нужно ).

P.S: Частично решение нашел здесь: [Snippets - выбор элемента в WPF по правому клику до вывода контекстного меню](https://purs.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/snippets-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-wpf-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE/). Но в таком случае элемент выделяется, но не возможно вызвать контекстное меню.

P.P.S Сам уже излазил все что можно и потратил уйму времени, но все равно никак не разберусь. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите решение по ссылке и уберите из него `e.Handled = true;`

```
<TreeView ... PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="tv_dep_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" >
```

В коде:

```
private void tv_dep_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch<TreeViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as TreeViewItem;

    if (treeViewItem != null)
    {
        treeViewItem.Focus();
    }
}

static DependencyObject VisualUpwardSearch<T>(DependencyObject source)
{
    while (source != null && source.GetType() != typeof(T))
        source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

    return source;
}
```